# Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 327 of 438 bytes (Opencart)

Tags: php, serialization, opencart, cpanel, softaculous

I just cloned my Opencart 1.5.6.1 site with Softaculous in cPanel, so I can make changes in the test site before applying it on the live site.

After clone success, my site has this message appear on the top:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 312 of 1130 bytes in /home/jefferso/public_html/test2/index.php on line 69

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 913 of 5545 bytes in /home/jefferso/public_html/test2/index.php on line 69

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 327 of 438 bytes in /home/jefferso/public_html/test2/index.php on line 69
```

The whole site looks weird, all products not accessible, even the admin.
Address: http://jefferson.com.my/test2/

Anyone has idea?

Comment: Looks like you edited some serialized settings in the database directly while corrupting the serialized string - PHP can not unserialize it back. I recommend to open the `settings` table, look for rows where `serialized = 1`, taking out the serialized values and trying to unserialize them in some simple script on your local machine. If you find a problem try to fix it - look for what is going wrong at mentioned offsets.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your stores database in phpMyAdmin or heidisql, change value `TEXT` to `LONGTEXT`.
2. `EMPTY` data on `SETTING` table, and restore.